# Display an Image in ScrollView

Tags: android, image, scrollview, center

How do i force the ScrollView to diplay the image's center as defualt?
I have a bitmap that is bigger the the ScrollView's viewport and i need to display the imge's center in the center of the viewport.
Thank,
Eyal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the properties for the view in the XML file. Using android:layout_gravity or android:gravity equals center might solve the problem.